# Joint Convexity Proof

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $x$ be $n \times 1$ vector and $Y$ be $n \times n$ matrix. 
Prove that $f(x,Y) = x'Y^{-1}x$ is jointly convex in $x$ and $Y$ when $Y \succ 0$.

Comment: convex w.r.t. which cone in codomain? The positive semidefinite one?

Comment: It's not even a scalar function. (Yes, I'm aware of cone-convexity of the type user251257 refers to. Given the low quality of the question I'm inclined to assume that's not what was meant.)

Comment: hint: Show that $f$ is convex in each argument first. Then you get the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you leaving out some assumptions?  What if $n=1$ and $Y$ is negative?

EDIT: With the new assumptions, we may consider a line segment through $(x,Y)$ space: $x = x_0 + t x_1$, $Y = Y_0 + t Y_1$, where $Y_0$ is positive definite and $Y_1$ is symmetric.  It is enough to show that 
$\left.\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} (x' Y^{-1} x)\right|_{t=0} \ge 0$.  Now if $Z = Y_0^{-1/2} Y_1 Y_0^{-1/2}$, $w_0 = Y_0^{-1/2} x_0$ and $w_1 = Y_0^{-1/2} x_1$, 
$$Y^{-1} = (Y_0^{1/2} (I + t Z) Y_0^{1/2})^{-1} = Y_0^{-1/2} (I - t Z + t^2 Z^2 + \ldots) Y_0^{-1/2}$$
so
$$ x' Y^{-1} x = (w_0 + t w_1)' (I - t Z + t^2 Z^2 + \ldots) (w_0 + t w_1)$$
and $$\eqalign{\left.\dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} (x' Y^{-1} x)\right|_{t=0} &=
w_0' Z^2 w_0 - w_1' Z w_0 - w_0' Z w_1 + w_1' Z^2 w_1 \cr
&= (Z w_0 - w_1)'(Z w_0 - w_1) \ge 0}$$
Thus it is indeed jointly convex.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was missing some assumptions. Hope it is right now.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to prove this is to take advantage of the fact that a function is convex if and only if its epigraph is convex. In this case, the epigraph is
$$\left\{(x,Y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\times\mathbb{R}\,|\,Y\succ 0,~x^TY^{-1}x\leq z\right\}$$
But consider this linear matrix inequality:
$$\begin{bmatrix} Y & x \\ x^T & z \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$$
Combine this with our knowledge that $Y\succeq 0$, and the Schur complement rule for semidefinite matrices gives us this:
$$Y\succ 0, ~ \begin{bmatrix} Y & x \\ x^T & z \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad Y\succ 0, ~ z - x^TY^{-1}x \geq 0 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad Y\succ 0, ~x^TY^{-1}x \leq z$$
Therefore, the epigraph is the intersection of one strict LMI and one non-strict LMI, both describing convex sets. As the intersection of two convex sets, the epigraph is convex, and so the function is convex.